# Javascript Confirm Dialog Not Activiting

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

Here is code:

```
<form  method="post" id="cp_ind_form">

    // lots of input fields!
    <input type="submit" name="update_submit" value="Update"  />
    <input type="submit" name="delete_submit" value="Delete"  onclick="deleteConfirm()" />

</form>
```

**scripts.js** (confirmed that this file is connected to above page)

```
(function deleteConfirm() {
    var s = document.getElementById('confirm');
    s.onchange = function() {
        var yes = confirm('Do you really want to delete this location?');
        if (yes) { 
            var f = document.getElementById('cp_ind_form');
            f.submit();
        }
    }
})();

}
```

This is driving me insane.  Such a basic function is not working here?  I am basically copying it from other code that I have that DOES work, and this is no different.  Can someone confirm if I am missing a small detail?

Comment: Have you looked at the error console? There should be a syntax error, your brackets don't match

Comment: What errors do you receive when you submit?

Comment: look at the bracket in the scripts.js . maybe there is a } on the wrong position. Which elment has the id "confirm" ?

Comment: I do not receive any error.    I am using Aptana IDE.  Don't really use it with JS much so didn't think to look for errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the code.

You are adding an onchange event to something when you click the submit.

You are not triggering the confirm to be shown, and you are not cancelling the original submission.

AND it makes no sense to have it wrapped with (funciton(){})();

It should be

```
function deleteConfirm() {
    return confirm('Do you really want to delete this location?');   
}
```

and

```
onclick="return deleteConfirm();"
```

Comment: This was best answer for me.  Wow, so basic.  Yet so effective.  Marking correct when time allows...

Answer (score 2):

To actually execute the confirm when `deleteConfirm` is called, change your code to this:

```
function deleteConfirm() {
    var yes = confirm('Do you really want to delete this location?');
    if (yes) { 
        document.getElementById('cp_ind_form').submit();
    }
    // block default submit
    return(false);
}
```

This also returns false so that the default form submission doesn't happen.

Then, change your HTML to this:

```
onsubmit="return deleteConfirm()"
```

If you handle the onsubmit instead of onclick, you can block the default submit by returning false from the handler.

Comment: You are doubling up the submit. button and the .submit()

Comment: @epascarello - no, it returns false to block the default submit.

Comment: actually it does not since there is no return on the onclick!

Comment: This DOES get the box to show, but hitting delete STILL deletes the location

Comment: @KickingLettuce - I added a mod to your HTML so that the default submit is blocked.

Comment: I am going with @epascarello answers, but thanks.  Marked you up as well.

Answer (score 1):

`deleteConfirm()` is run on button click. Inside this function you are assigning code to the event`onchange` which than waits for the item `#confirm` to be changed. I don't know where is that element but I pressume the event is never fired so the confirm box never shows